# meteor cucumber test server.call in step definition Error: Method not found [404]

Tags: unit-testing, meteor, cucumber

I am new to Meteor Cucumber I am trying to do a basic test
Check a new user
Here is the step definition code

```js
this.Given(/^I am a new user$/, function () {
    server.call('fixtures/reset').then(function() {
        server.call('fixtures/seedData');
    });
});
```

I get

```
Error: Method not found [404]  ...
  at World. (/tests/cucumber/features/step_definitions/static_page.js:17:20)
```

which points to the first `server.call` (column 20 is the c of call).

Here is the feature
   Given I am a new user

Here is the fixture

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    Meteor.methods({
        'fixtures/reset': function () {
            Meteor.users.remove({});
        },

        'fixtures/seedData': function () {
            Accounts.createUser({
                email: "bob@example.com",
                password: "testtest"
            });
        }
    });
})();
```

Here is the package.js

```js
Package.describe({
    name: 'fixtures',
    version: '0.0.1',
    summary: '',
    git: '',
    documentation: null,
    debugOnly: true
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
    api.versionsFrom('1.2.1');
    api.use('ecmascript');
    api.addFiles(['fixtures.js'],['server']);
});
```

I don't understand why this code is failing
It is based on http://www.mhurwi.com/a-basic-cucumber-meteor-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a package for your tests? That's not necessary. At the root level of your Meteor app folder, make a directory called "tests". My structure looks like this:

```
tests
└── cucumber
    ├── features
    │   ├── artist
    │   │   ├── artist-login.feature
    │   │   └── step_definitions
    │   │       └── artist-login.js
    │   ├── support
    │   │   └── hooks.js
    │   └── viewer
    └── fixtures
        └── artist-fixtures.js
```

You don't need any closures in your fixtures file. This is mine:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'reset': function () {
    Meteor.users.remove({});
  },

  'createTestAccount': function () {
    Accounts.createUser({
      email: 'test@user.com',
      password: 'test123',
      profile: {
        firstName: 'Test',
        lastName: 'User'
      }
    });
  },

  'isLoggedIn': function () {
    return !!Meteor.userId();
  }
});
```

If you're writing a Meteor package and want to test it, use TinyTest.

Comment: Your solution works. I thought a fixture package would enable to share the methods with jasmine unit tests

Comment: I have followed the same tutorial and ended up with the same problem.  I have copied your structure and removed the code around Meteor.methods but I get a ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined and my tests won't even begin to run.  How do I make Meteor available inside the tests fixtures?

Comment: @macasas Hold off for now, xolvio:cucumber is now deprecated, and Meteor 1.3 will have its own official testing platform.